# Linking javascript file to html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to javascript and trying to add this http://codepen.io/jklm313/pen/EarFd  great map scrolling effect to my site. Css anf HTML read fine, but the js part doesn't want to work. Even if I put the js code in my html. This is the very typical beginning of my html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
        <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
```

I've searched for clues, but I can't seam to find the issue, is the code outdated or should I add something more? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Test and make sure you are getting the js file loaded into the page. One method would be to place at the top of the script.js file :
    alert('loaded');

If you get the alert box then you you have the correct path. If not then you know it is likely a path issue. You may need to make sure your file is in the same directory or else specify the directory in the src

I just glanced at the link and notice it is using the jquery library. Go to jquery.com to learn how to include that js file as well